# login block has disappeared from /user

Tags: nodes, users, theming

The content region throughout the site seems to have disappeared.  I believe this might be a result of some mishandling of the default settings in Omega.

As a result the login prompt is gone from /user and I'm currently logged out without a way to log back in and fix it.

Any idea how I can login to the site without going to /user or how I would go about editing Omega/delta so that I can bring back the content region without logging in?  This site is still local/on my development server.  So I can still access the files.

Attached is a screenshot of what I'm looking at for those who are confused. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could print the login block programmatically in (the top of ..) your page.tpl.php like

```
<?php
 $block = module_invoke('user', 'block_view', 'login');
 print render($block['content']);
?>
```

clear caches through drush if possible

```
drush cc all
```